# Simple Find in Atom without Replace

Tags: atom-editor, key-bindings

In Sublime Text ctrl-F does a Find, Ctrl-H does a (Find and) Replace. In Atom Ctrl-F does a Find and Replace. 
Is it possible to link a keybinding in Atom to a simple Find? The reason is a Find saves vertical space.

I noticed that ctrl-f in Atom does the following:

```
'ctrl-f': 'find-and-replace:show'
```

but there does not seem to be a command for a simple command such as 'find:show'

Comment: You can also take a look at different themes.The City Lights theme for example uses a different layout for the Find/Replace box, with the find and replace input boxes on the same line: https://atom.io/themes/city-lights-ui

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `find-and-replace` package only implements two views. If you want a simple find feature, you would need to create a package for that. The code is available in [a GitHub repo](https://github.com/atom/find-and-replace), and if you're fluent in JavaScript, it actually wouldn't be hard to fork the package and create a new view from the existing code.